# Get indices in pandas series while using str.findall

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on finding the rows which contain a particular string. the dataset has close to 1 million rows. Here is a simple example;

```
text=['abc USER@xxx.com 123 any@www foo @ bar 78@ppp @5555 aa@111www','anontalk.com']
text=pd.Series(text)
srhc=text.str.findall('www')
srhc
```

And the output is;

```
0    [www, www]
1    []        
dtype: object
```

Is it possible to efficiently (i.e. programmatically) just obtain the list of indices, which contain the text `www`. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for a specific sub-string use `.str.contains()` ;

```
text = ['abc USER@xxx.com', 'helowww', '123 any@www', 'foo www', '@5555 aa@111www', 'anontalk.com']

text = pd.Series(text)

text[text.str.contains('www')]
```

Output;

```
1            helowww
2        123 any@www
3            foo www
4    @5555 aa@111www
dtype: object
```

To get the index of these;

```
text[text.str.contains('www')].index.to_list()

# or this 
text.index[text.str.contains('www')]
```

Ouput;

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and replies, colleagues. It is really helpful. All of them seem to be working. But it seems I can only select one of the replies as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `str` `contains` with `nonzero`

```
srhc=text.str.contains('www').to_numpy().nonzero()[0]
srhc
Out[66]: array([0], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `text.index` with `str.contains()`:

```
srhc = text.index[text.str.contains('www')]
print(srhc)
```

Prints:

```
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more efficient to do a list comprehension to get your indexes, especially since there is nothing unique or special about the index of the series

```
text=['abc USER@xxx.com 123 any@www foo @ bar 78@ppp @5555 aa@111www','anontalk.com']

#I use this to stay true to your question
text=pd.Series(text)

#this gets you the index/indices
#which is what you want, based on your question
[index for index, entry in enumerate(text) if 'www' in entry]

[0]
```